# Python script running header from interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Noob warning

I have a script I'm trying to run (`rename_oturep.py`) in the cmd prompt. When I run `python rename_oturep.py` I get this error:

```py
File "rename_oturep.py", line 1
    Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, it seems the script is reading from the header from the interpreter when I try to run that script.

E.g.

Input:

```
X:\Python 3.8> python
```

Output:

```py
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I have deleted the header info in IDLE & honestly have no idea why it is reading the interpreter header as part of the script. I have run this script successfully before (a couple of weeks ago) with no issues. Why is this just now an issue? Anyone have a similar experience?

Here is the actual script code (copypasta direct from IDLE):

```py
import sys

import re


info = []


with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fasta_in:
    for line in fasta_in:
        info.append(line.replace('\r', '').rstrip('\n'))


seqs = []

list
for index, item in enumerate(info):
    if index == 0:
        ID = re.search('Otu[0-9]*',item[1:]).group(0)
    else:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            ID = re.search('Otu[0-9]*',item[1:]).group(0)
        else:
            seqs.append((ID, item))


with open("clean_repFasta.fasta", 'w') as fasta_out:
    for item in seqs:
        fasta_out.write('>' + item[0] + '\n' + item[1] + '\n')
```

Comment: IDLE also provides a text editor beneath the interactive shell. You should use this editor (or another editor program) to write scripts. Your "script" is a log of an interactive shell session and not valid Python code (especially the > at the beginning of each line).

Comment: The > at the beginning of each line is left-over from my pre-edit OP. Those aren't actually in the script. I have Copied & pasted the script from GitHub into the editor & saved. Minus the >'s the script above is what I'm using. It has worked fine in the past. I'm only now running into this error using the exact same script as before (when it worked).

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `>` from the lines beginning.

The python file should look like to get rid of the syntax errors

```
import sys

import re

info = []

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fasta_in:
    for line in fasta_in:
        info.append(line.replace('\r', '').rstrip('\n'))

seqs = []

for index, item in enumerate(info):
    if index == 0:
        ID = re.search('Otu[0-9]*', item[1:]).group(0)
    else:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            ID = re.search('Otu[0-9]*', item[1:]).group(0)
        else:
            seqs.append((ID, item))

with open("clean_repFasta.fasta", 'w') as fasta_out:
    for item in seqs:
        fasta_out.write('>' + item[0] + '\n' + item[1] + '\n')
```

Comment: The original script does not have the >'s. That was an artifact from my original question. It was edited but I didn't take out the >'s from the OP. The script I'm using does not have those characters in the code.

Comment: post your python file somewhere please as it is now

Comment: Just uploaded to https://github.com/jhines1/python4SO/blob/master/rename_oturep.py

Comment: checked, it should work, please post as well how you trying to run the script & error & the stacktrace of the error

Comment: When I type ```python rename_oturep.py file.fasta``` I get the error stated above in the OP.